# angular-formly custom template for signature pad

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

So I'm trying to write a custom template for the [angular-formly](http://docs.angular-formly.com/) librarythat uses the [signature pad directive](https://github.com/legalthings/angular-signature) as a field. I've been able to use the basic template method to get the signature pad to show up:

```
app.run(function(formlyConfig) {
    formlyConfig.setType({
        name: 'signaturePad',
        template: '<signature-pad accept="accept" clear="clear"' +
            'height="220" width="568"></signature-pad>' +
            '<button ng-click="clear()">Clear signature</button>' +
            '<button ng-click="signature = accept()">Sign</button>'
    });
});
```

However, the issue that I'm having is that the `signature` variable that accepts the return value once the Accept button is clicked is not accessible in the scope of the main controller.

Perhaps a clearer version of the problem would be:

```
 app.run(function(formlyConfig) {
    formlyConfig.setType({
        name: 'helloWorldButton',
        template: '<button ng-click="vm.clicked()">Sign</button>'
    });
});
```

How can I access the a function `vm.clicked()` inside of the application controller. The form itself is declared within the ng-controller scope:

```
<div ng-controller="controllerName as ctrl">    
    <form ng-submit="ctrl.onSubmit()">
        <formly-form model="ctrl.userData" fields="ctrl.userFields">
            <button type="ctrl.submit">Submit</button>
        </formly-form>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure a different way of getting this to work, for anyone concerned.

```
app.run(function(formlyConfig) {
    formlyConfig.setType({
        name: 'signaturePad',
        template: '<button ng-click="openSigPad()">Sign</button>',
        controller: function($scope, $uibModal) {
            ...
            $scope.openSigPad = $uibModal.open(...);
            .then(function(result) {
                $scope.model[$scope.options.key] = result;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This way, I created a modal using UI Bootstrap, display any necessary info in that, and then return the modal result back to the model of the field itself. Works great.